# JavaScript: Is it allowed to use a `ternary` statement inside an `if` statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

In the following script, I've used a `ternary` statement in the `else if` portion of an `if` statement, juxtaposing the two. In a case like this, should I substitute another `if` statement inside the `else if`?

```
var attackOpt = prompt('Which attack option does Angelo use in this turn?');

// Remaining number of times Angelo can cast spells:
var angMP = 3;


// Validity Check to see if the attack option entered can be executed:
while (true) {

        if (attackOpt === 'slash') {
            break;
        }

        else if (attackOpt === 'magic') {
            (angMP) ?
                 break;
                : attackOpt = prompt('Angelo can no longer cast spells. Select again.');
        }

}
```

Comment: Should? It's semantics and highly subjective.

Comment: You can use a ternary statement anywhere a statement is allowed, however you can't put a semicolon in the middle of it (`break;`).

Comment: As long as it executes without error this is up to you. I, personally, would call this terribly ugly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have a ternary operator expression (it's not a statement) anywhere an expression is allowed.

**But** a ternary operator uses expressions as its 3 arguments. `break` is not an expression, but a statement. You can't use `break` there.

You'll have to use an `if` statement.

Comment: Ah, I see! The code didn't run because I had 'BREAK' in it. Here I was thinking that the reason for this error might well be something to do with the duality of 'if' and 'ternary'. Which is why I posted this question. Looks like I was of the mark. If I hadn't asked, my misunderstanding would have led to false knowledge.

Comment: @pourraitpuet-etre Feel free to up vote and/or accept the answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work but it makes the code difficult to read. Consider revision to your 'while' loop instead:

```
while (attackOpt !== 'slash' && angMP) {
   attackOpt = prompt('Angelo can no longer cast spells. Select again.');
}
```

Of course, this is a stylistic choice and entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. It will result in syntax error and the code won't run. Ternary operator is used to return values quickly without if-else. No breaks are allowed. However, you can use something like that, in a single line:

```
if (angMP) break; else attackOpt = prompt('Angelo can no longer cast spells. Select again.');
```

Or even the simpler form in other parts of your code:

```
if (angMP) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

not needed it will work properly without any problem

```
(angMP) ? break : attackOpt = prompt('Angelo can no longer cast spells. Select again.');
```

Comment: The grouping operator (brackets) around *angMP* aren't required, I think it's more semantic to write `angMP? break : ...`.